# Nvidia-driver-460 graphics driver stops Ubuntu 20.04 from booting

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

Recently, (somehow) my boot loader broke and I had to reinstall Ubuntu. I still had troubles with Grub and finally have got it healthy and working again.

As I was setting up some software and changed my graphics driver over from xorg to nvidia-driver-460. After restarting the computer would not boot and just had a blank screen after grub. After reverting and tweaking what I could I tried it again and this time I have the Ubuntu logo show up (though it was at a lower resolution than when booting with xorg) and it spins for a while and it seems to freeze here.

I've now reverted back to xorg (through the recovery shell) and everything is fine. But I'd really like to get these nvidia drivers since I want to play a few games.

I didn't have any warnings show up so I don't have more information. If there is info I can get then I would be happy to add it.

The odd thing is that before my boot broke I had 20.04 and nvidia 460 running no problem. Does any one have ideas? Perhaps a new update to ubuntu or some broken config?

Edit:
[image]

Switching to the top one, 460, means ubuntu won't boot. Xorg here works fine (evident by me taking a screenshot with it).

Comment: X.Org is not a display driver it is a display server. I would suggest adding more detailed information like the exact steps you are taking, commands you are executing and errors you are receiving.  You cannot replace X.Org with Nvidia drivers, or the other way around.

Comment: I see the confusion. `nouveau` is the name of the open source display driver.  There seems to be other problems here that preceded your current one: a brand new installation should not have all of these problems. Perhaps something is wrong with your installation. Or maybe something you did to "fix" another problem caused this one.  Are you using the most recent version of installation media for 20.04?  Did you choose proprietary drivers and accept online updates during installation?  Are you installing Ubuntu to a clean formatted drive or setting up dual boot config?

Comment: It's a bit of a long story. I used to have dual boot with windows but have since gotten rid of windows (though a boot for it is still found on a drive it was never installed on). I had problems with the boot after settings crashed and reinstalled. It did not install grub when doing a clean install so I did it manually (that's my fix). Now my boot is fine but switching to nvidia seems to break it. Updates during install yes, normal drivvers, I choose the "erase disk and install". The stick I have for ubuntu is maybe a month old so missing too many updates.

Comment: I suggest that you make sure that you have the most up to date installation media.  Then format the hard drive GPT before you install Ubuntu. When you install Ubuntu, make sure that you select the option to use proprietary drivers if you want to use proprietary drivers. It makes no sense to select the open source drivers during installation if you plan on immediately replacing them.

Comment: Now it is likely just poor memory but I feel like I've never seen the option to install proprietary drivers on install. However, on all my past installs of Ubuntu (including the one directly before this) I have always installed the same 460 driver through the GUI with no problems. I even had used the clean install option so I am really out of ideas. I can't see how reinstalling would change much here. Besides, the last backup I had just didn't work when I restored so I am losing faith in technology.

Comment: Yes, during installation, there is an option to install 3rd party software and drivers. There is also an option to download updates during the installation. You should choose both options if you wish to use the Nvidia drivers. IIRC, the 20.04 installer explicitly asks you if you want to use nouveau or Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed `nvidia-driver-450-server` and this has allowed me to use my GPU for the time being. It appears the current versions of 460 have a bug where they will not work with display port connections (which is what I am using).

We will have to wait until a new version is available to upgrade.

Comment: I think I'm facing a similar problem. Can you tell the exact steps that you followed to fix it? And what are display port connections?

Comment: `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450-server` or use the drivers GUI (search 'drivers' on ubuntu). Restart and it *should* be good. Display port is a type of cable connector like HDMI or VGA.